# How to stop webserver (implemented through web.py and threading)

Tags: web.py

I have implemented simple webserver using web.py. 
And through multithreading module, I am able to run multiple instances of webserver listening on separate ports.
Now all the instnces are listening http requests forever. and I want to step a particular thread.
Is there a way to stop an instance from listening (or kill particular thread altogether.)

Answer (score 1):

**api.py**

```
import web
import threading

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
)


class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "I'm lumberjack and i'm ok"

def run():
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    t = threading.Thread(target=app.run)
    t.setDaemon(True) # So the server dies with the main thread
    t.setName('api-thread')
    t.start()
```

---

**frame.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import api

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
api.run() 
web.load(QUrl("http://0.0.0.0:8080/"))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```